# PDO: could not pass variable to prepare

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP PDO bindValue in LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit)

```
    $number=8;
    try {  
        $topics=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM topictable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?");
        $topics->execute(array($number));       
        $topicarray = $topics->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
        print_r($topicarray);
    }  
    catch(PDOException $e) {  
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }
```

Above is my code, I know the problem comes from `$topics=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM topictable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?")` because when i change ? to 8, it works. Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: Because `LIMIT` cannot be set this way. Also, you have much larger problem in the root of your SQL: [read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9946238/727208)

Comment: @tereško thanks for your article. However, is there a proper way to pass number to limit in PDO?

Comment: Hey @tereško, I modified the codes you given and end up with some new problems. Do you mind come to [here to help me a bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963941/sql-getting-8-distinct-random-row-from-a-table-with-two-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$topics=$dbh->prepare("...LIMIT :limit");
$topics->bindValue(':limit', intval($number), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$topics->execute();
```

Comment: you do not need to cast value, if you are binding it as `PDO::PARAM_INT`

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44639 PDO can still be buggy about casting it as a string.  better be sure it's an int first.

Comment: "This only happens on emulated parameter binding, i.e. when PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES is TRUE.". If you do not know how to properly use PDO, maybe you should read a tutorial. Noone with half-a-brain is using emulated prepares.