# I need to pull data from 6 random records but I'm having a bit of trouble

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Doing a while / loop to get 10 random results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945691/doing-a-while-loop-to-get-10-random-results)

I'm making a website which people can upload funny pictures they take or make. Each time the home page is loaded, a random picture/record is displayed from the MySQL database onto the page. This is done with...

```
$filename = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT filename FROM pictures ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"));
echo $filename[0];
```

This would echo a random pictures file name onto the page. Something like `funny_cat`. But then I need the file type so that I can echo out the image onto the page. Like this...

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE p='$p'"))) {
    $filetype = $record["filetype"];
}
echo "<img src=\"picture/".$filename[0].".".$filetype."\" />";
```

All is good.

Now here's the bit I'm struggling on. I'm wanting to display 6 other random smaller pictures onto the page. So I need to get 6 random records and echo the `filename` and `filetype` for each record. The thing that needs considering is I can only get random records with the technique I used above due to the way the database is set up. How could I do this?

If there is anything you're unsure about please say and I'll try explain. Also, please explain your solutions. Thanks!! ***:-)***

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to query the file type in order to generate the `<img>` link. You just need the file name. The type should be reported by the web server in the `Content-Type` header of the response when the user agent downloads the image. But if you need i anyway, you can get the file name and type together in one query. You don't need 2 queries.

Comment: @Celada - Please could you explain how I could get it in 1 query?

Comment: @Skiroid see how `filename` and `filetype` are queried together in [agam360's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984603/i-need-to-pull-data-from-6-random-records-but-im-having-a-bit-of-trouble#10984710). But anyway I notice that what you call "file type" is not really the file type: it's just a second piece of the filename, appended to the first piece of the file name plus a dot. Why don't you just store the entire file name in a single database column? The way you've done it, the filename is forced to contain at least one dot!

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the first 6 results of the randomized list by changing your query's limit to 6.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT filename FROM pictures ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6")
```

Then, you can call mysql_fetch_row 6 times to get all 6 file names.

```
$filenames = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $filesnames[] = $row[0];
}
```

Now, you have all 6 file names, and you can do image retrieval for each.

Comment: -1: while this will actually make the OP code 6x faster, it still will be slow and getting slower with each new entry in the table

Comment: @tereško What do you propose to increase performance?

Comment: Reading [this article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) should explain the issues and possible solutions (and mybe a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9946238/727208) i wrote in a similar topic)

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly you wanted to "replicate" the random fetch 6 times.
If so I'd do something like so:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){
   $filename = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT filename,filetype FROM pictures ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"));
   $file =  $filename[0].'.'.$filename[1];
   echo "<img src=\"picture/".$file."\" />";
}
```

Note:
If you are fetching a big amount of data, don't use the rand function, but rather create a random array in php and fetch the relative ids.

**Edit:**

If you wanted a solution on retrieving 6 different and random pictures (so they won't repeat themselves) I would do something like so:

```
$arr_ids = array();
    for($i = 0;$i < 6;$i++){
    $fresh_rand = rand()*$db_row_count;//$db_row_count the number of rows in the data base
     for($j=0;$j <count($arr_ids);$j++){
      if($fresh_rand == $arr_ids[$j]){
        $j =0;
         $fresh_rand = rand()*$db_row_count;
      }
     }
     $arr_ids[$i] = $fresh_rand;
    }
```

Then I would fetch from the db, the ids from the $arr_ids array.
My solution was made in a hurry, so forgive me for the bad practice, but I hope you understood what you need to do.

Comment: you can repeat the result this way

Comment: repeat what? are you addressing the OP?

Comment: "SELECT filename,filetype FROM pictures ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1", the same filename can be displayed twice

Comment: He didn't ask for that solution, that is another story... I understood that he wanted to repeat it 6 times. (plus, the probability is low for it to repeat it self)