# How to use while loops in mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

Am sorry for the really stupid question. i have a code like so and i would like the result to be done on a while loop. i was using mysql befor and the query was simple and executed well.
example

```
$sql_query = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query)
 {
   $data_a = $row['a']; $data_b = $row['b'];
 }
```

now i use oop and i have a database class and a connection handler that is injected in to the new class am extending from the database class. my proble no is after the code executes, i get this error method *mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()*  here is my code

```
<?php
class recentWorks extends DatabaseModelBase
{

public function show($tbl, $num_to_show, $site_url="") 
{

    $statement = $this->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$tbl.' WHERE RAND()<(SELECT (( '.$num_to_show.' /COUNT(*))*10) FROM '.$tbl.' ) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT  '.$num_to_show.'  ');
    $statement->execute();
    while ($recent_results = $statement->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $featured_work_name=$recent_results['name']; $featured_work_url=$recent_results['url']; $featured_work_thumb=$recent_results['img_thumb'];
        $featured_work_id=$recent_results['id'];$featured_work_desc=$recent_results['desc'];$featured_work_img=$recent_results['img_url'];
        ?>
  <li> 
  <a href="<?php echo $featured_work_img; ?>" class="fancybox thumb poshytip" title="Click To View Enlarged Image">
  <img src="<?php echo $featured_work_thumb; ?>" width="282px" height="150px" alt="<?php echo $featured_work_name; ?>' Image" />
  </a>
 <div class="excerpt">

 <span class="main_header"><a href="<?php echo $featured_work_url; ?>" target="_blank" class="poshytip recent-link" title="Click To Visit Website"><?php echo ucwords($featured_work_name); ?></a>
 </span>
<?php echo substr($featured_work_desc,0,300); ?>
</div>
</li>
        <?php
    }
    $statement->close();
    }

  }
 ?>
```

please someone debug this for me

Comment: If you can avoid it, please don't use the mysql_* functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: You might find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9946238/727208) to be relevant for your subject.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what you had *before*

```
$sql_query = mysql_query($query);
   `----- missing error checking and handling
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query))
         `---- missing error handline
{
    $data_a = $row['a']; $data_b = $row['b'];
           `----- complicated way of setting variables as arrays
}
```

Now let's see what you have now (selected lines)

```
$statement = $this->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$tbl.' WHERE RAND()<(SELECT (( '.$num_to_show.' /COUNT(*))*10) FROM '.$tbl.' ) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT  '.$num_to_show.'  ');
                       `---- using prepare as if it would have been mysql_query()
$statement->execute();
            `----- same here
```

This is wrong. Just telling you. I suggest you search for some well-working `mysqli_*` tutorial first. One that either explains you how to build SQL queries and fire them *and* that explains what [*prepared statements*](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) are and how to use them.

My suggestion: Start with the PHP manual, it compares the different libraries and shows examples for all mysql, mysqli and PDO.

You have even a comparison side-by-side of mysql and mysqli for a more easy migration: [Dual procedural and object-oriented interface](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php).

Comment: thanks for your kind review and suggestions. however, do you have and links i could check? most of the question on stackoverflow here are not solving my problem.

Comment: I edited the question and left two link, feel free to reload. Also *browse* the manual pages from the extension. Look for examples there, an answer here on SO can not do the same work as the manual does. Keep on reading ;)