# Pull 5 random records from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, random

I am trying to write a php / mysql script that will pull 5 random records from the DB and display them. At the moment I am using the following to pull one record out and display it in a module, but im not sure how to pull out 5 at a time only. I will have approx 200-300 records in the DB in total.

I am currently using the following code to pull the single record out at random :

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `zgjzb_chronoforms_data_submitbusiness` ORDER BY     RAND() LIMIT 0,4;");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

Comment: `LIMIT 5`. don't use mysql_*, don't use `ORDER BY RAND` on a large table

Comment: Use a while loop, this is clearly shown in the many examples available in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945691/doing-a-while-loop-to-get-10-random-results

Comment: @tereško - It's a duplicate, but note that two of the three answers (including the accepted answer) are terrible. The only good answer to that question is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9946238/535871), but it requires a stored procedure.

Comment: @TedHopp , yes, it requires a stored procedure, because fast selection of `N` **unique** entries is a not-completely-trivial problem in SQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want to use `ORDER BY RAND()`. MySQL has to build a temporary table. If your table has a unique id column, something like this is much better:

```
SELECT * FROM `zgjzb_chronoforms_data_submitbusiness` 
WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `table` )
ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

See [this blog post](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/) for other approaches that work well in php.

Comment: Thanks, will this pull out 5 records ?, or do I just change LIMIT to 5 ?

Comment: @IainSimpson - It will pull out one record. You don't want to use `LIMIT 5` because it will pull out 5 _consecutive_ records, which aren't really random. It's cheap enough, though, that you can just do it multiple times until you get 5 unique records.

Comment: i don't think 200-300 is so large that order by rand() is going to hurt performance wise. But i'm not going to benchmark it to check :-)

Comment: @Dagon - I'm not going to benchmark it either. :)

Comment: dam you! my evil plan to cajole you in to it failed! :-)

Comment: @IainSimpson change the `LIMIT 5` .. You need to try and test it yourself for something. Then you know understand better and why..