# How to echo random row from database?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL: How to retrieve a random row or multiple random rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586858/mysql-how-to-retrieve-a-random-row-or-multiple-random-rows)
>   [Pull 5 random records from mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351718/pull-5-random-records-from-mysql-database)

I have a large list of domains in my database in the table "list" under the column "website".

There are about 140 million rows and I just need to know how to echo a random one.

Basically like this:

```
<?php include('directory/database.php'); ?>

WHATEVER CODE WORKS FOR GETTING A RANDOM DOMAIN FROM THE DATABASE

<?php
echo $domain;
?>
```

There's just a huge amount of records so I need to know the quickest way to just have one of them randomly selected and displayed on a page.  Thanks!

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211329/quick-selection-of-a-random-row-from-a-large-table-in-mysql

Comment: Everything that I've found on Google and StackOverflow have answers like simply using `SELECT * from TABLE order by RAND() LIMIT 1`  - I need something that will work on a table with 140 million rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely don't want to use `ORDER BY RAND()`. MySQL has to build a temporary table. If your table has a unique id column, something like this is much better:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `table` )
ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

See [this blog post](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/) for other approaches that work well in php.

Note: This simply repeats [my answer on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13351767/535871).