# Select rows randomly if a column's condition met

Tags: php, mysql

My ads_man table has the following structure;

[image: ads_man table structure]

I want to select rows randomly from this table *if* column "rotate" is 1, otherwise if rotate = 0 then it shouldn't select these rows randomly. I've tried this;

```
$query = $db->query("
    SELECT type,place,code
    FROM ads_man
    WHERE approved = '1' AND fid = '{$fid}' AND place = '{$zone}'
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 3");
```

It selects the rows randomly but *issue is* I'm unable to find a *quick* way to select these rows rather to use another query to find all those rows having rotate = 1 and then use `ORDER BY RAND()` in the query mentioned above.

Please help!

Comment: You can't have both in one step. Doesn't make much sense. You either select randomly or not. If I've got it wrong, please post a sample expected output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doing a while / loop to get 10 random results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945691/doing-a-while-loop-to-get-10-random-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
$r_q = $db->query("SELECT rotate FROM ads_man");
$r = $db->fetch_array($r_q);
if($r['rotate'] == "1")
{
    $rotate = 'rotate = "0" OR rotate = "1" AND';
    $order_by = 'ORDER BY RAND()';
}
else
{
    $rotate = 'rotate = "0" AND';
    $order_by = 'ORDER BY dateline DESC';
}

$query = $db->query("
    SELECT type,place,code
    FROM ads_man
    WHERE {$rotate} approved = '1' AND fid = '{$fid}' AND place = '{$zone}'
    {$order_by}
    LIMIT 3");
```

Comment: @user2854563 , keep in mind, that as table approaches total of 1000 rows (and more), the penalty caused by `ORDER BY RAND()` will become noticeable. At 10'000 rows the penalty will probably already be in range of few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = $db->query("
    SELECT type,place,code
    FROM ads_man
    WHERE rotate='1' AND approved = '1' AND fid = '{$fid}' AND place = '{$zone}'
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 3");
```

Comment: You're wrong. I know how to use rotate column inside the query, instead I've asked how to select the rows randomly *if* rotate = 1, otherwise it should select rows normally if rotate != 1

Comment: You didn't understand what `user2854563` is asking.. he is asking to randomly pic row(s) if column's condition met 1, however NOT if column's condition met 0

Comment: Thanks for trying sir! I've used Imran Omer's method and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this:

It's not very clear what you need but, if you need 3 rows with `rotate = 1` selected randomly and then others (for example 7) with `rotate = 0` then you can do it with an `UNION`

```
(SELECT type,place,code
    FROM ads_man
    WHERE rotate = 1 AND approved = '1' AND fid = '{$fid}' AND place = '{$zone}'
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT type,place,code
    FROM ads_man
    WHERE rotate = 0 AND approved = '1' AND fid = '{$fid}' AND place = '{$zone}'
    LIMIT 7)
```

Is this what you need? Let me know if not

Edited: Forgot parenthesis

Comment: Somewhat close to what I'm after. But if I use LIMIT 3 then still its selecting 5 rows from table. However I'm using LIMIT 3

Comment: Thanks for trying sir! I've used Imran Omer's method and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to add a random number column by `ALTER` statement in given table. That will save lot of time.

Comment: What are you talking about ??

Comment: I meant, along with the original table, if you add a random column by `ALTER your_table ADD random DEFAULT rand();` then you can sort and select array using random number

Comment: I think rotate column does exactly what you're saying, so there is no need to have another column that does the same thing.

Comment: Yeah. why the need for another column?

Comment: Nope, that would persist the value upon insertion and use that value forever. Not much randomness in that... ;)