# how to get last 10 and then show random 5

Tags: php, mysql

hello all i am a php developer and right now i am having a simple issue like i want to get the last 10 data out of my database table and then show random 5 out of them .

like see the code below.

```
$random=rand(0,18);
mysqli_query(
    $connection,
    "SELECT something1,something2 
     FROM `table` 
     where (id !='0') 
     ORDER BY time DESC 
     LIMIT 4 OFFSET $random");
```

this query selects last 4 updated fields randomely out of 18 but i want a something better solution to this

Comment: Just order by `RAND()` in the query instead of doing it in PHP?

Comment: is'nt this the same with your problem?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945691/doing-a-while-loop-to-get-10-random-results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, define "the last 10"; for now let's assume the last ten when ordered by time. So, that is in fact the *first* ten when I order them the order way (I guess you got that):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (id != '0') ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10;
```

then we subselect that to randomize and limit:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (id != '0') ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10;
) A ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Remember, your database is *extremely* powerful and fast, use it for any data-processing.

Comment: is this query equivalent to one or two queries ??

Comment: This is one query, using a subselect.

Answer (score 0):

In case you prefer randomizing in PHP, you can use PHP's [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

```
<?php
$last_10_rows = mysqli_query($connection, "simple query to get last 10 rows");
shuffle($last_10_rows); // randomize the array
$random_5_rows = array_slice($last_10_rows, 0, 5); // take first 5
?>
```

For

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is a great solution with Select. Your sample take 4 line in a row with an OFFSET which is not a truly random selection. You should limit your select to 10 and then get 5 row of the 10 by another php code.

```
$rows = mysqli_query($connection,
    "SELECT something1,something2 FROM `table` where (id !='0') 
     ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10");

//then, get 5 random key from your array of row from the mysql select
$rand_keys = array_rand($rows, 5);
```